# Exporting images to parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am able to import json file from Parse.

```
{

  "results" :
[

     {
        "playerName" : "name1",
        "score": 100,
         "pic" : ?
     },

     {
        "playerName" : "name2",
        "score": 200,
        "pic" : ?
     }

  ]
}
```

But how to import json along with images?

Comment: Are you asking how to get image URL ?

Comment: @martobile can you post more about it

Comment: In Parse.com there options for Add class and Import .json files to create a table. Json file should be like array of maps and each map will be treated as a row in table. So my question is how to insert a file in map and import that in parse ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write script to download images from parse. I found an interesting post related to same, refer it once.

https://calorious.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/episode-1-exporting-data-and-images-out-of-parse/